# htaccess remove ?category_id=xxxNumbers

Tags: .htaccess, filter, categories

I need your help after to check everywhere. Because Google Webmaster Tools view them as the duplicate Titles and Descriptions.

I need to remove some of parameters from my complex URL.

```
FROM:
http://3dstreaming.org/3d-media/videos/7006-avatar-3d-2009-half-sbs-full-hd-1080-dual-hdf-orn.html?category_id=567

TO:
http://3dstreaming.org/3d-media/videos/7006-avatar-3d-2009-half-sbs-full-hd-1080-dual-hdf-orn.html


where "7006-avatar-3d-2009-half-sbs-full-hd-1080-dual-hdf-orn.html"
7006=variable value
avatar-3d-2009-half-sbs-full-hd-1080-dual-hdf-orn=variable words

and remove ?category_id=567  ("?category_id=xxxNumbers")
```

and then the same for the following parameters:

```
"?start=xxxNumbers"

"?filter_tag=xxxWords"

"?pattern=xxxWords"
```

Could someone help me?
Thanks in advance

I tried with this but doesn't work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+?&)category_id=[^&]*(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following to your htaccess should achieve what you are looking for

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?category_id=   [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?start=  [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?filter=  [OR]  
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?pattern=    
RewriteRule ^  %{REQUEST_URI}?%1 [L,R=301]
```

**OR**

adding the following will remove **ALL** parameters from a url

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /([^\?\ ]*)\?
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R=301]
```